# Leaderboard misaligned on different digit ranks

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

When I search somebody up, this happens:

[image]

As you can see, the profile images are misaligned vertically.

Also the hat count. This is a bug, and should be fixed to make it look better.

When you're searching some user up, there might be other users with a similar name that have less hats and lower ranks, and therefore, their profile images get misaligned.

I drawed a black line to show the difference.

I can see why this happens, it's because the rank number is 5 digit instead of 3 digit.

Comment: It's still messed up :(